# Extended classes compile perfectly in Eclipse but not in cmd

Tags: java, eclipse, cmd, classpath

My program consists of classes that extend other classes. The problem is, when I try to compile them in **cmd**, system says **"Cannot find symbol"**. Some sites discussing similar problems mention including the source folder in the CLASSPATH. I did as they said and it still gives the same error. However, it runs smoothly in Eclipse. Any ideas why?

Comment: All the classes you need to compile, and the libraries needed to perform the compilation, must be defined at -classpath option. Something like this: `javac -classpath path/to/everything`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you compile the top level class first. If you try to compile a class extending other class, and you don't have compiled `.class` file for that class, you will get that error.

```
package pkg1;
class A { }

package pkg2;
import pkg1.A;
class B extends A { }
```

For the above code, you should compile the `.java` file containing your `class A` first to get your `.java` file containing `class B` compiled. Also, set the path containing your `class files` in your classpath.

In Eclipse, it works because it automatically compiles your classes as you save them.

**NOTE: -**

If you are having your classes under some packages, then compile your java files using this command: - `javac -d . A.java`. This will create a folder for the package name and put the class file in that folder automatically. Then your class B would be able to find it

Comment: I tried compiling them in the right order. Using your example, what happens is:
1. A is compiled.
2. When i try to compile B, compiler says "Cannot find symbol: A".

Comment: can you explain to me why CLASSPATH could ever matter in this case? I have all files in one folder...

Comment: Are you sure the path containing your `A.class` is in your classpath? For E.G, if your path is: - `D:\somePath\myclasses\A.class`, your classpath should contain: - `D:\somePath\myclasses`

Comment: @atLANtis. Are you having your classes under some package?

Comment: Yes, could the package naming be a problem? The files are all in the same package

Comment: @atLANtis. So, if you are having packages for your classes, then compile your java files using this command: - **`javac -d . A.java`** This will create a folder for the package name and put the class file in that folder. Then your `class B` would be able to find it.

Comment: @atLANtis. Yes, you should have your class files inside a folder hierarchy resembling your package structure. Follow the above commad to compile your files. It would work.